# How to add a button to the Android system navigation bar?

Tags: java, android

I need to add an additional button to the right of the system buttons, as shown in the photo. clicking on it will perform a specific action related to my app. Can this be done?

[image]

Comment: No this cannot be done. The system bar is for the Android OS only, not for use by apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: No.  There's not an API for this, only the OS can control the navigation area.  Consider also the problems you'd run into with the variety of system navigation styles available, many of which, like gesture navigation, don't even have buttons.

Some apps fake things with screen overlays that reimplement some or all of the navigation and/or hide the system navigation, but you're going to run into all of the above issues doing so, plus the issues inherent in screen overlays, plus you'll have no guarantee that however you do it will continue to work into the future.  I wouldn't recommend trying this approach.